# Having both Visual Studio Professional and Ultimate Installed can I remove only the professional?

Tags: installation, uninstall, visual-studio-2010

I want to free a Visual Studio 2010 Professional license, so my company can use it on another computer, by removing it from "Add/Remove Programs". But I fear it can damage my Ultimate installation. What is the safest way of doing that?

Comment: Its not possible to have two versions of VS2010 installed.  The simplest solution is to just repair the installation of VS2010 Ultimate if it causes a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound yes it is possible.

Comment: @Ramhound experience proves otherwise

Comment: @user193426 - Considering both use the same installation directory by default I don't see how its possible.  I still say just fix the installation to VS 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: I had Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed and working. I installed Visual Studios 2012 Professional, and it appears that it installed a set of things Pro uses in place of certain Ultimate features (couldn't tell you what they were). That said, when I run Visual Studio, it runs the Ultimate edition. I don't know how (and think it's not possible) to run the lesser edition. But they do install just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not use activation, so you would be fine with having both versions inatalled.

Comment: Sorry, what kind of activation are you talking about, and what it does have to do with the licensing management?

Comment: uninstalling Professional worked fine, apparently Ultimate wasn't affected

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

I had two versions of VS2012 installed that I could see clearly in Control Panel's *Program Features*:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

A year ago, when I installed Ultimate 2012, I don't know why MS had them be installed side-by-side, rather than just upgrading VS Premium 2012.

After uninstalling VS Premium 2012 (via their uninstall tool), VS Ultimate 2012 still worked for me.  I also saw reclaimed hard drive space, though not as much as I thought I should have seen.

Hope this helps! Good question.

Comment: Certainly can. I'm currently looking at Profession and Premium versions of 2012, both listed as 11.0.50727.1 I'm scared to uninstall professional as it takes so long if it messes up my install lol :)